# How to access the MSO slideshow controls in Indesign JavaScript

Tags: javascript, controls, slideshow, adobe-indesign

**How can access the slideshow controls.**

```
function mso_html_convertion_slide_show() {

        var mso_total_count = MSO.states.length;

          for (var i = 0; i < mso_total_count; i++) {

             MSO.states[i].name;
       }

}
```

[image]

Thank you,